# AX 2009 - Shop Floor Control > Registration (time clock) job stuck in active status for one user/one job

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

We have one user who is having issue w/clocking and his time card. If you look under his Raw Registrations in Shop Floor Control, there's a job that got stuck in "active" status a few weeks ago, and we have pinpointed this as the issue. On the screen, the column header is "Work in Process", but the field in the table is actually "JobActive" and is a NoYes field. The table is JMGTERMREG in the AOT, friendly name "Raw Registrations".

The time has already been transferred so the record cannot be fixed the correct way. I could find no other way in the system itself to force this job for this one user to "inactive". Is there any way via an AX screen to force this?

Since I couldn't find any, in a test environment I forced this value "behind the scenes" (I went into SQL, which I know is a no-no, so please don't yell at me) to change it to "0", aka, inactive, aka no longer in process. I'm worried about ramifications beyond resolving the user's problem. We have tested it in the test system, and the user's issues have gone away, and others can log into the job successfully, but I'm just worried there might be other things affected. Can anyone reassure me doing this in Prod won't blow something up? And I don't mean reassure me by giving me a blankie or a stuffed animal. ;)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothings blows up, you are good to go.

I have seen this error before, and the workaround for me was to make a job to fix it. I also think I fixed the error, but I am to old to remember how and where.